# How do you prove the following inequality according to Chernoff's bound?

Tags: inequality, probability-distributions, bernoulli-numbers

I came across the following problem when I read the book, [**"Understanding Machine Learning: from theory to algorithms"**](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf). You can click the link to download the book.

The statement is on **Page 399**. When you arrive at Page 399, you can search the keywords "**Chernoﬀ’s inequality implies**". **Then you can find the whole inequality**. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aA6l.png) is the snapshot of the statement:
[image]

Let $X_1, ..., X_m$ be independent Bernoulli random variables, whose sum is $Z$, each having probability $p \in (0,1)$ of being equal to $1$.

Please prove that

$$P[Z\le \frac{pm}{2}]\le e^{-\frac{2}{mp} (mp-\frac{mp}{2})^2}$$

I have read some reference materials in Wikipedia, [Chernoff's bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound), but **I did not find any theorem or inequality to get the solution straightforward**. Hope you can help me!

Comment: Hi @Ben, please make an effort to show what you have already tried, including reading the Chernoff Wikipedia article.

Comment: I have added what I have tried.

Comment: Great! Which materials did you read? And how close were they to giving the right solution?

Comment: That is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound. And I have also updated the question! I'll be looking forward to your answer.

Comment: So your exponent is equal to $-mp/2$. A lot of the results on the Wikipedia page easily gives $-mp/8$. This is the kind of thing that would be useful for you to state in the question, so we know that it's not just a typo that you put it that way.

Comment: You can also put information about where in the book you found the statement. Since I'm pretty sure it's wrong (and the right exponent should be $-mp/8$), so I spent time on finding the book myself, but it's long, and I've looked at all the places "Bernoulli" appears, and I still can't find it.

Comment: I didn't wrongly input the inequality. And I have added what you requested. Thank you very much. I'll be looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101115/discussion-between-ben-and-thomas-ahle).

Comment: Thank you, I think the question is much better formulated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is apparently a mistake in your book. One example where the bound $\Pr[Z\le mp/2]\le\exp(-mp/2)$ is wrong, is $p=1/8$, $m=16$.
Then the bound says $\Pr[Z\le mp/2]\le\exp(-1)\approx 0.37$, while in actual fact $\Pr[Z\le mp/2] = \Pr[Z\le 1] = (1-p)^{16}+16(1-p)^{15}p \approx 0.39$.

The real best bound you should use from [Chernoff (or Hoeffding)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Additive_form_(absolute_error)) is
\begin{align}
\Pr( Z \leq \varepsilon m)\leq\exp\left(-\frac{(\epsilon-p)^2 m}{2p}\right).
\end{align}
In our case, setting $\varepsilon=p/2$, we get $\Pr( Z \leq pm/2)\leq\exp(-mp/8)$.

This bound is completely fine for the application in the book, since on the previous page, $m$ is defined to be $\ge\frac{8}{\epsilon}(2d\dots)$, and this factor of 8 is simply ignored in the proof. Thus everything works out well, and maybe the $/8$ version was even what was originally intended, since otherwise it's a bit weird to have that factor of 8 flying around in the theorem.

Sorry you ran into a bad proof. Computer scientists are often fairly sloppy with their constants when they use Chernoff bounds.

Comment: When setting $\epsilon = \frac{p}{2}$, how can we get $\Pr[Z\le mp/2]\le 1/2$? Could you provide the whole derivation? I'll be looking forward to your answer. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Once you have $/8$, you just plug in the lower bound for $m$ stated on the previous page.

Comment: Could you provide the detailed derivation, please? I'm still puzzled about the derivation from $e^{-m\epsilon /8 }$ to $\frac{-dlog(\frac{1}{\delta})}{2}$. Hope you can help me! I will really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Ben They're just doing a very rough bound. Basically saying that $d + \log1/\delta < d \log 1/\delta$.  You probably have to ask a new question to make it sure exactly where things go bad when you're trying to follow their argument..